# ¿Me pueden decir donde esta el error? - Cola de Enteros

Tags: java

Realice este código que tiene como objetivo ingresar un conjunto de números y permitir realizar distintas operaciones y hasta ayer funcionaba correctamente, hoy por error creo que lo modifique en algo, aunque no se muy bien en que, el problema ocurre con la tercer opción del siguiente menú, este ocurre específicamente solo cuando una opción diferente fue llamada anteriormente, si se hace de primeras no ocurre nada y lo elimina correctamente.

public class OperacionesDeCola {

```
private Queue<Integer> colaDeEnteros = new LinkedList<>();

public OperacionesDeCola(){
}

public OperacionesDeCola(Queue<Integer> colaDeEnteros){
    this.colaDeEnteros = colaDeEnteros;
}

public int mayorNumeroDeElementos(){
    Queue<Integer> aux = new LinkedList<>(); 
    int mayor; // variable que guardara el mayor valor de la cola
    mayor = 0;  // asignamos 0 al valor mayor
    do{ // ciclo
        if(mayor < colaDeEnteros.peek()){ // mayor es menor que el valor en primer posicion
            mayor = colaDeEnteros.peek(); // el valor en primer posicion sera el nuevo valor
        }
        aux.offer(colaDeEnteros.poll()); // llenamos la nueva cola a la vez que vamos vaciando la original 
        // ESTE CICLO CAMBIARA CADA VEZ QUE SE LEA, EN LA 2DA VUELTA EL 2 VALOR SERA EL PRIMERO,Y ASI CONSECUENTEMENTE. 
    }while(!colaDeEnteros.isEmpty()); // siempre y cuando tenga contenido 
    this.colaDeEnteros = aux; // devolvemos el valor original a la cola
    return mayor; // retornamos el numero mayor
} 

public int sumaDeElementos(){
    Queue<Integer> aux = new LinkedList<>(); // cola auxiliar para regresar valores originales
    int suma = 0;  
    do{
        aux.add(colaDeEnteros.peek());
        suma += colaDeEnteros.poll();  
    }while(!colaDeEnteros.isEmpty());
    this.colaDeEnteros = aux; 
    return suma; 
}

public int eliminarElemento(){
    int elementoEliminado; 
    elementoEliminado = colaDeEnteros.remove(); 
    return elementoEliminado; 
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    String cadena = ""; 
    for (Integer elemento : colaDeEnteros)
        cadena += elemento + " - ";
    return cadena; 
}
```

}

public class AplicacionColaDeEnteros {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    // OBJETOS
    Queue<Integer> colaDeEnteros = new LinkedList<>();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    // OBJETOS
    
    // VARIABLES
    int generacionOpcion; 
    int numeroEntero; 
    int menu; 
    int enteroMayor; 
    int sumaDeEnteros; 
    int elementoEliminado; 
    // VARIABLES
    
    // CREACION DE COLA 
    do{
    System.out.println("Generacion de enteros: 1) Automatica | 2) Manual");
    generacionOpcion = entrada.nextInt();
    }while(generacionOpcion < 1 || generacionOpcion > 2 );
    
    if(generacionOpcion == 1){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            colaDeEnteros.offer((int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
        }
    }else{
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese el numero: "); 
            numeroEntero = entrada.nextInt(); 
            colaDeEnteros.offer(numeroEntero);
        }
    }
    OperacionesDeCola cola = new OperacionesDeCola(colaDeEnteros);
    // CREACION DE COLA
    
    // MENU 
    System.out.println("¿Que desea hacer?");
    do{
        do{
            System.out.println(cola.toString());
            System.out.println("| 1. Mostrar mayor numero de elementos | 2. Mostrar suma de elementos | 3. Eliminar un elemento | 4. Cerrar");
            menu = entrada.nextInt(); 
            switch(menu){
                case 1:
                    enteroMayor = cola.mayorNumeroDeElementos();
                    System.out.println("El elemento mayor en la cola es: " + enteroMayor);
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    sumaDeEnteros = cola.sumaDeElementos();
                    System.out.println("La suma de los elementos es: " + sumaDeEnteros);
                    break; 
                case 3:
                    elementoEliminado = cola.eliminarElemento();
                    System.out.println("Elemento eliminado: " + elementoEliminado);
                    if(colaDeEnteros.isEmpty()){
                        System.out.println("La cola fue vaciada completamente");
                        System.exit(0); // cerramos el programa
                    }
                    break;
            
            
            }
        }while(menu < 1 || menu > 4); 
    }while(menu != 4);
    // MENU
    
}
```

}

Otra cosa que no tiene sentido es que se supone el mensaje solo se imprimirá si la cola esta vacía, sin embargo el elemento supuestamente borrado ni siquiera es el ultimo elemento de la cola, sino el primero de la misma.

CASOS DE USO:

- Usando la eliminación de elemento apenas la cola es creada
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Usando otras opciones antes
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: @Bicho en el primer caso elimina elemento por elemento, pero si hago una opción diferente antes esta se vacía completamente, cuando se supone que la cola ya fue establecida a los valores originales una vez se realiza cualquiera de las opciones 1 o 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Tu lógica vacía la copia original y al mismo tiempo creas una copia. Pero haces la comprobación de si la cola esta vacía sobre la copia original**.

Desde *Aplicacion* pasas una referencia a *colaDeEnteros* que mantienes en *cola* como un atributo.

En cada operación de *OperacionesDeCola*, vacias la cola que tienes y haces una copia, y asignas al atributo la nueva cola.

Pero en *Aplicacion*, la variable *colaDeEnteros* sigue apuntando a la cola original (que vaciaste al llamar por primera vez a *sumaDeElementos* o *mayorNumeroDeElementos*). Es esa la que usas para comprobar si está vacía.

Lo que deberías hacer es añadir el método *isEmpty* a *OperacionesDeCola* para que haga la comprobación sobre la última "copia" de la cola que has creado, e invocar a ese método en vez de al de la variable *colaDeEnteros*.

Otra opción sería usar siempre la instancia original, y después de haber hecho la operación que quieras volver a copiar los elementos desde *aux* hacia la cola original, de forma que tanto *Aplicacion.colaDeEnteros* como *OperacionesDeCola.cola* apunten siempre al mismo objeto. Recomiendo la primera, ya que es feo que desde *Aplicacion* accedas directamente al estado del objeto.

Y ya para nota, probablemente la cola se debería crear/rellenar con métodos en *OperacionesDeCola*, sería más elegante. *Aplicación* así no conoce la implementación de *OperacionesDeCola*, solo sabe que tiene un método "anyadirEntero" al que tiene que pasar los números que le llegan desde consola.

En otro orden de cosas, mi enhorabuena por la meticulosidad a la hora de hacer la pregunta.

Comment: no estoy seguro si lo de meticulosidad fue sarcasmo, pero en todo caso, me excuso en que tenia un poco de prisa jajaja y muchos pendientes, intentare agregar lo de la creación de la cola, aunque según recuerdo no lo había hecho por un inconveniente que ocurrió en su momento, por lo demás gracias por tu respuesta, aun me confundo un poco con el uso de objetos y que pertenece a cada cosa, pero bueno echando a perder se aprende(¿

Comment: No es para nada sarcasmo, lo digo muy en serio. Hay muchísimas preguntas por aquí de gente pidiendo ayuda pero sin dar la información necesaria, está bien ver preguntas como ésta.